# Mass create an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I'd like to create a 10x10 (doesn't neccessarily need to be 10x10 but have 100 elements) array with each element containing an object with properties as follows:

```
const myObject = {
   value: undefined,
   xCoord: undefined,
   yCoord: undefined
}
```

Each object will represent a position of the array which can conceptually be viewed as a square.

e.g. The top left corner will contain the object with x, y Coords as (1,1).
Top right: (1,10)
Bottom left: (10,1)
Bottom right: (10,10).

My questions are:
How do I add/ push myObject into each of the array elements and have the Coords set correctly automatically as they're pushed in?

How do I write a function to access each element that takes a value for the x and y Coord property and then returns the corresponding value? So if myObject in say the 14th element (counting from 1) I can call the function with x:2 y:4 and it will return 23:

```
myObject {
   value: 23,
   xCoord: 2,
   yCoord: 4
}
```

Comment: If you're storing the objects in a two dimensional array, why bother storing the coordinates in each? You're just duplicating data

Comment: The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. This would fit nicely in [StackSnippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: You are making it yourself more difficult by starting from 1. An array index starts at 0.

Comment: Thanks all. I'll provide a code snippet when I can next time, good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the empty array, then push an object there. Then in the function simply filter the array based on x and y.

```js
coords = [];

coords.push({
 "myValue": 25,
 "x" : 15,
 "y" : 14
});

coords.push({
"myValue": 15,
 "x" : 5,
 "y" : 4
});

function getCoords(x,y){
    return coords.filter(obj => obj.y == y && obj.x == x)[0]["myValue"];
}

console.log(getCoords(5,4))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create arrays of a specific length and use the *map function* to generate the values.

For example

```js
const size = 10

const matrix = Array.from({ length: size }, (_, x) =>
  Array.from({ length: size }, (_, y) => ({
    value: x + y, // not sure what this is meant to be exactly
    xCoord: x + 1,
    yCoord: y + 1
  })))
  
function getValue(x, y) {
  return matrix[x - 1]?.[y - 1]?.value
}

console.info(getValue(2, 3))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```